# What is MEM in Heroes of the Storm statistics?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

In Ctrl-Alt-F there's a few settings that appear.  I am specifically looking for what `MEM` means.

Here's a picture:

[image: Picture of Ctrl+Alt+F]

Comment: It would improve your question a lot if you included a screenshot of the screen you are referring to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MEM stands for memory, which is the total amount of memory the game is currently using. You can check this number against that in the Task Manager.

[image: Image of MEM]

The reason for the discrepancy in values is that the Task Manager updates slower than in-game, which is updated realtime.